# Refresh view in xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm new to Xamaring and iOS, but I'm trying to create a view that when the UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add is pressed, it adds a record to the SQLite database, alerts the user and then refreshes the screen as the screen draws out a button for each of the records in the table in SQLite.

Currently the add button code is:

```cs
this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, (sender,args) => { 
    conn.Query<Job>("INSERT INTO Job (Job) VALUES(0)"); 
    UIAlertView alSQL = new UIAlertView("Jobs","New job added",null,"ok",null);AllJobsScreen(), true);
    alSQL.Show ();
}), true);
```

At present the data is added and the alert is shown, but I'm not sure of anyway to get the screen to reflect this new record in the database and add a new button.

I've looked online for refreshing the screen and can't find anything so any help would be great. Or if I'm going about this the wrong way, please let me know.

I'm writing out buttons on the screen, but ideally I need to be able to refresh any view with anything on it. At present the buttons are written out in a loop from a SQLite query as below:

```cs
UIButton btnTest = new UIButton (UIButtonType.System);
btnTest.Frame = new RectangleF(iTopLeftx, iTopLefty, 300, 30);
btnTest.SetTitle("J00000" + s.mJobID.ToString(),UIControlState.Normal);
btnTest.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
this.View.Add (btnTest);
```

Comment: You must be using a TableView to display the records right? Just reload the data in that.

Comment: Can you post your code that sets up what is displayed on the screen? If you are not using `UITableView`, you should just this code in a function and call it where needed.

Comment: The code writing out the buttons has been added. If this isn't enough detail please let me know. I didn't want to put too much on there. I ideally need a way of disposing the view as soon as the user leaves it so that when they navigate to it again, it recreates it from scratch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `TitleColor`, `BorderColor` and `BorderWidth` of your newly created `UIButton`s. Maybe your buttons are displayed on the view but you just can't see them.

```
UIButton btnTest = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
btnTest.Frame = new RectangleF(iTopLeftx, iTopLefty, 300, 30);
btnTest.SetTitle("J00000" + s.mJobID.ToString(), UIControlState.Normal);
btnTest.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
btnTest.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
btnTest.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
btnTest.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
this.View.Add(btnTest);
```

**EDIT**

Then the problem seems to be that you didn't remove previously added `UIButton`s. Try to hold your collection of `UIButton`s in a list or an array.

`List<UIButton> buttonList`;

Then populate your `buttonList`:

```
private void PopulateSubviews()
{
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        UIButton btnTest = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
        // previous code withoud this.View.Add(...);
        ...
        buttonList.Add(btnTest);
    }
}
```

And have these two methods:

```
private void ClearView()
{
    foreach (UIButton btn in buttonList)
    {
        btn.RemoveFromSuperview();
    }

    buttonList.Clear();
}

private void InitializeSubviews()
{
    foreach (UIButton btn in buttonList)
    {
        this.View.AddSubview(btn);
    }
}
```

And to refresh your views:

```
private void ReloadSubviews()
{
    ClearView();
    PopulateSubviews();
    InitializeSubviews();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. They appear fine on screen, but if I change the data, navigate away from the page, then back to the page, it still shows the same screen with the same buttons, I can't work out how to update what is showing upon re-entering the screen.